# Handle play/pause commands from AirPods while being in-call

Tags: objective-c, swift, callkit, mpremotecommandcenter

Is there any way to handle a headset command while staying in an audio/video call originated from the same app?

I'm working on the app that uses CallKit to make calls, and recently I got a task to allow muting a call when the user double-taps on AirPods (next track command). Currently, any action will result in a call being ended, and I could not find a workaround to modify this behavior. The same thing is happening with FaceTime and native calls.

So far, I tried using MPRemoteCommandCenter to respond to remote commands, e.g.

```
import MediaPlayer
 
let remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
Log.i("Setting up a remote command event handler.") 
remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { (action: MPRemoteCommandEvent) in
  Log.i("Detected nextTrackCommand: \(action)") // Never is printed
  return .success
}
remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
assert(audioSession.category == .playAndRecord)
```

All my ideas failed as the callback didn't get called. At this point, I'm starting thinking this is a hardware limitation.